# How to GET all the ALL DATA from WTForm?

Tags: python, flask-wtforms

**How To get All Data in a wtf form with a single command in a dictionary or list without needing to write this much lines of code, specifing every single element in the form and geting data seperately
**

```
@app.route('/add', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def add_cafe():
    form = CafeForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print("True")
        cafe_name = form.cafe_name.data
        cafe_location = form.cafe_location.data
        opening_time = form.opening_time.data
        closing_time = form.closing_time.data
        coffee_rating = form.coffee_rating.data
        wifi_strength_rating = form.wifi_strength_rating.data
        power_socket_availability = form.power_socket_availability.data
    return render_template('add.html', form=form)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The `wtforms` documentation says that that's `Form.data`](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/forms/#wtforms.form.Form.data):

> A dict containing the data for each field.

In other words,

```
@app.route('/add', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def add_cafe():
    form = CafeForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        data = form.data
        print("True", data)
        # ...
    return render_template('add.html', form=form)
```